# How to alternate a row color for a Bootstrap grid system

Tags: razor, bootstrap-4

I have a loop on my MODEL in the view and I simply want to make every alternate Div ROW a different color. Is there a way I can check if my variable i Modulus by 2 ==0 and then set the backcolor, or is there even a better way

```
                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Transactions.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label asp-for="@Model.Transactions[i].TransactionId" />@Model.Transactions[i].TransactionId
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own answer uses the right modulus operator to check for an even/odd index value.

> I don't know if this the best way to do it but below is how I overcome my issue

Adding a class name instead enables more style flexibility. (The snippet below assumes you have a section called `Styles` in your `_Layout.cshtml`.)

```
@section Styles {
    <style>
        .odd-row {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        .even-row {
            background-color: #e1e1e1;
        }
    </style>
}

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Transactions.Count; i++)
{
    string altClassName = i % 2 == 0 ? "even-row" : "odd-row";
    <div class="row @altClassName">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Transactions[i].TransactionId">@Model.Transactions[i].TransactionId</label>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this the best way to do it but below is how I overcome my issue

```
<div class="row" style="@(i%2 == 0 ? "background-color:aliceblue" : "background-color:white")">
```